# Okta Implicit Callback issue with dynamic base url for angular application

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, okta

I am trying to implement okta authentication using okta hosted login. I have run the sample application found [here](https://github.com/okta/samples-js-angular/tree/master/okta-hosted-login) and everything works fine. But when I change the `base href` of `index.html` then the issue comes. As per my requirement my application root url won't be simply `example.com/` it is `example.com/development/console/` so to achieve this I had to change the `<base href="/">` to `<base href="./">`. When I change this I am getting empty page with `Loading ...` message and in developer tools I see error for loading all the js, css, ... file.

If I look in developer tools I found that the URL it looking for assets is wrong …

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/implicit/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
GET http://localhost:4200/implicit/polyfills.bundle.js 404 (Not Found)
```

It should be

```
Request URL: http://localhost:4200/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css
GET http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js
```

I raised same question [here](https://devforum.okta.com/t/implicit-callback-issue-for-angular-failing-to-load-css-js-all-assets-when-base-url-in-index-html-is-dynamic/2185) .

Please let me know how to handle this issue to fix.

Comment: Please don’t cross post. We get notifications from Stack Overflow and our developer forums and it creates more work for us to answer in both places.